# vuejs: how to pass data to child component in method

Tags: vue.js

im looking to apply animation.css animations to components before they are destroyed.To do this, i have to get all divs with the class imageDisplayBody and add certain classes.However ,i dont know a way to keep track of how many components are being destroyed and i need that to access the right component  when i try to acess the classes.I have thought about catching the beforeDestroy at the parent component level with @hook:beforeDestroy but i dont know how to pass the the counter data to the child component right after

```
<template >
    <div >
        <div class="imageDisplayBody">

            <router-link :to="{ name: 'photoDescription',params:{pic} }">
                <h4>{{pic.title}}</h4>
                <img :src="pic.url" alt="">

            </router-link>

        </div>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
    name:'imageDisplay',
    components :{

    },
    props :['pic','load','compteur'],
    methods:{

    }
    ,
    beforeDestroy(){

        var contenu=document.getElementsByClassName("imageDisplayBody") 
        [this.compteur-1];
        contenu.classList.remove("animated");
        contenu.classList.remove("bounceInRight");
        contenu.classList.remove("animated");
        contenu.classList.remove("bounceOutLeft");


    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
    img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    h4{
        height: 50px;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to apply an animation before destroyed! in SPA usually it only will be destroyed when you leave the app not on internal routing within the app. So when you initially load the app, the whole thing loads and changing routes doesn't destroy anything.

Comment: Maybe <transition> is what you are really looking for. Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/changjoo_park/tf8p8jve/